# How can I install or compile androidmk tool in linux?

Tags: android, android-build

I am trying to use androidmk tool to convert Android.mk file to Android.bp. But I don't know from where I can download that. Please give a little more detail about this.

I tried cloning https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong but don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 4):

You need the whole AOSP to build `androidmk`.

You can get AOSP with `repo` ([which you need to install first](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading#installing-repo)).

```sh
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b pie-release
repo sync
```

After you downloaded your AOSP copy with `repo init` and `repo sync`, you build and run it like this:

```sh
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch
m androidmk
androidmk [flags] <inputFile>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also can you please provide me the link to download that. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Download `repo`? It's behind the link I just added.